# sharepoint: Server.Transfer?

Tags: sharepoint

I am writing some code for sharepoint to transfer from this page to another page:

```
Server.Transfer("/DefectManagement/DefectList/default.aspx")
```

But I got this problem:

```
Error 1 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Topology.Server' does not contain a definition for 'Transfer'
```

How would this issue be done in sharepoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [SPUtility.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.redirect.aspx)

Comment: Everywhere I look for an answer to this question I see this response, but SPUtility.Redirect does something very different than Server.Transfer.  Is there truly no way transfer to a page on the server in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 4):

The Server reference you have there (Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Topology.Server) is not the Server reference (System.Web.HttpServerUtility) you are looking for.

Try

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer();
Page.Server.Transfer();
```

And yes, SPUtility.Redirect is better for sharepoint